# Passing a property from parent to (adult) child in Australia (NSW)

Tags: taxes, real-estate, australia, trusts

My father is retiring and would like to pass on the family home to my sister and me. We are both adults now and do not live in the home. I should also so mention, we are based in Sydney, Australia.

The house is paid for completely and there is nothing owing on it. I would prefer to rent it out instead of selling it as I believe it has room to increase in value over the years.

We are trying to figure out what the options are:

1. Title change - this incurs a stamp duty tax at the current valuation.
2. Gift deed - same as above, need to pay the taxman.
3. Power of attorney - keep the property in my dad's name and be the power of attorney to manage it.
4. Family trust - this is the one I am not as certain on even with my googling

I am wondering if a family trust is a good structure in this scenario, as I am sure it is a common one. Is it worth it, with all the complexity and costs?

I don't believe there will be capital gains tax to be paid as the house has been his main residence during the transfer. However, there will be capital gains tax based on the difference in valuations at the time of renting it out and when/if we sell it in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: How far do you live from the house? (You'd be the landlord, and maintaining, screening tenants, collecting rent, etc takes time and effort.) What does your sister want?  Think strongly about KISS and either buy out your sister or sell it outright.

Comment: I agree with @RonJohn Sell the house and split the money with your sister. Much simpler and less litigation prone.

Comment: @RonJohn Thanks for the comment. We live about 30mins away from the house. I was thinking of getting a property agent to manage this, but I still need to do the numbers. KISS - Keep it simple stupid? She is happy to rent it out as well.

Selling it is definitely an option.

Comment: Yes, that's KISS; I say it to myself all the time...  She might be fine with it, but remember: don't mix family and money, **especially** when one is doing all the work.  (Family-run businesses break that "rule" all the time, but it's still good to keep in mind.)  If you do all the work, but she gets 50% of the profits, eventually you'll get bitter, so sign some form of contract where she acknowledges that **you** get a management fee, and she has **zero** say in who it's rented to.  (Imagine her promising a cheap rent to her boyfriend the lazy bum, and then not demanding payment.

Comment: CONT: or promising it to her best friend who's down on her luck.  Or getting mad when you say "No!", and remind her of the contract, then stirring family discord.)  So many possible problems...

Comment: All good points! Thanks for providing the perspective. Still early days on this process, so nothing is decided yet. Definitely agreeing to some form of contract is a wise idea, if we don't sell it straight away.

Comment: Will your father be claiming the pension at all? Because that will also affect the answer, as there are particular asset, income, and gifting rules that would be affected

Comment: in regards to point 4: You should only consider trusts when you are talking about millions to make it worth the administrative fees of the trustees etc. In Florida e.g. a family trust company may not be organized or operated with a capital account of less than $250,000. In Austrialia , the cost of establishing a family trust is relatively low. A trust generally costs $1,500 (plus GST) in legal documentation to set up, or $2,500 (plus GST) for a trust with a corporate trustee. But that's low figures - also keep loss of ownership of the assets in mind - they'd then belong to the trust..